# Passing MySQL fetched rows to thread pool in C

Tags: c

I want to process data fetched from the MySQL database simultaneously. I pass the data to each thread process (no need for thread-safe consideration; rows are processed independently in each thread):

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "thpool.h" // https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool

#define THREADS 10

struct fparam
{
  int id;
  char *data;
};

void process(void *arg)
{
  struct fparam *args = arg;
  // Processing ID and Data here
  printf("%d - %s\n", args->id, args->data);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  threadpool thpool = thpool_init(THREADS);

  // MySQL connection

  MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);

  int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
  struct fparam items[100]; // 100 is for the representation

  MYSQL_ROW row;
  int i = 0;
  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
  {
    items[i].id = atoi(row[0]);
    items[i].data = row[1];
    thpool_add_work(thpool, process, (void *)(&items[i]));
    i++;
  }

  mysql_free_result(result);
  mysql_close(con);

  thpool_wait(thpool);
  thpool_destroy(thpool);

  exit(0);
}
```

When there are many rows, `items` gets too big to fit in memory (not just heap).

How can I limit the number of rows stored in memory and delete them when they have been processed?

I think a key issue that we do not know if `process` function is faster or fetching the rows from the database.

Comment: What does "not just heap" mean? Are you saying you don't want to use heap? If so, why not?

Comment: @kaylum sorry, I added it later to avoid confusion for not using `malloc` in the code. I am fine with either heap or stack.

Comment: Are you saying there are so many rows of data that even dynamic memory will be too large? In that case you need synchronisation between the main thread and the pool threads to coordinate only reading more rows when a pool thread is ready to receive them. For example, use a counting semaphore.

Comment: @kaylum yes, this is exactly the problem. Too many rows even for dynamic memory. And I look for a way to read rows when a thread is free to process it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement a queue between your result set (a potentially HUGE #/rows) and your thread pool (a limited #/worker threads).

Comment: As you know, any time a system might have more data coming in than it can service in a timely manner, you should consider using some kind of "queue".  Here are several examples (you can find many more with a simple Google search): https://www.log2base2.com/data-structures/queue/queue-data-structure.html, https://www.programiz.com/dsa/circular-queue, etc. etc.  Your worker threads read the next available item ("dequeue") and service it.  Even though "servicing" can occur in parallel, your "dequeue" will probably need a lock.

Comment: I see that there are too many competing tasks here: fetching, loading, and processing. I suggest a simple mechanism that looks like a "queue for lazy ppl". Before firing your thread, you can check your memory limit, then strategize. If not full, fire the processing thread. If full, write the `data` to the storage at a file named `id` (considering it is unique, otherwise use a counter) for later processing. Now you have files with your data that you can access later at your good memory condition.

Comment: No one here take cares of DB? Please, why should you need process row by row? A batch operation is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create new queue in your scenario as `thpool_init(THREADS)` already provides you one and `thpool_add_work` feeds this internal queue and it grows on fetching. If fetching from database is fast but processing is slow you have to limit fetching new rows to reasonable rate so they will fit into memory. Looking into documentation of `"thpool.h"` there is this function `thpool_num_threads_working(threadpool)`. It will return number of working threads so as you defined `THREADS` in simplest form you would want to fetch new row whenever there is at least one idle thread available (Something like `while(thpool_num_threads_working(thpool) < THREADS)`).

Taking into account performance reasons you should think about prefetching some rows to have your data already there when any thread will finish its job to be able to feed it without waiting. How many of these rows can be there waiting on processing it depends on memory available. It is even more important to consider this when fetching can be quite time consuming but processing is fast.

The way you use `items[i]` also creates an issue here because `i` can go to infinity overflowing `items[100]` array. If we put there **very strong** assumption that threads are finishing their jobs in the same order as started you could just reset `i` in such way that `items` specific indexes would be reused for new rows (like `if(i>=THREADS) i=0;` as kind of very basic circular buffering). Unfortunately right now I am afraid `C-Thread-Pool` is not supporting identification which specific thread has finished its job (and which corresponding data are no longer needed). If You need to be 100% safe here i would consider two solutions possible. Extending `C-Thread-Pool` with thread status vs its job id verification or processing rows in batches in such way you feed all threads (one job per thread to queue) and then wait till all of them will finish their job to feed them all together again with next batch of rows to process.

And remember to check for errors when using `thpool_add_work` and `thpool_init`.

Comment: your third paragraph articulates my problem for which I am trying to find a practical solution.

Comment: Glad to hear that. From this point I believe you need to choose which approach You want to follow. The most elegant results will give extension to thread pool library. Easiest way would be processing in batches of 10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)), a list where you add items at one end and take them out of the other.

You can write your own; a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) can be used as a queue adding items to one end and removing them from the other. Or use an existing implementation such as [the one provided by GLib](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.Queue.html).

Comment: `queue` was suggested in the comments, but it does not simply solve my problem. I cannot pass the MySQL rows directly into threads. How can I store n number of rows to be read by the threads?

Comment: @Googlebot It's unclear why you need `items` at all. You could [create an `fparam` from the MySQL result and pass that directly into the worker](https://gist.github.com/schwern/07ee47caf08bebbe37c92dbcb6ef5fd6). If you could clarify what you plan to do with `items` once the worker has processed them that would help.

Comment: I got your point. I agree that `items` is superfluous. Thanks for the clarification.